# The use of System.currentTimeMillis() in loops in Java

Tags: java, halting-problem

Let's observe the following segment of code in Java that uses `System.currentTimeMillis()` in a `for` loop.

```
package loops;

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        final long MAX_VAL=Long.MAX_VALUE;
        final long CURRENT_MILLIS=System.currentTimeMillis(); 

        System.out.println("MAX_VAL = "+MAX_VAL);
        System.out.println("CURRENT_MILLIS = "+CURRENT_MILLIS);

        for(long time = 0; time < CURRENT_MILLIS; time++)
        {
            System.out.println("inside for = "+time);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `final long` type variable `CURRENT_MILLIS` holds the current millisecond maintained by the system which is always less than `(MAX_VAL)` the size of the `long` data type in Java though the `for` loop gets stuck into an infinite loop. How?

Comment: It is not an infinite loop, but one with billions of iterations. It just takes a very long time to complete. What's the point of this question?

Comment: There is no point of the question rather just a curiosity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are concerned about comparison between times you can use

```
while (System.currentTimeMillis() - start < RUN_TIME)
```

This could be a problem with nanoTime as it could overflow after 292 years.  However, with currentTimeMillis you have about 292 million years.

Answer (score 1):

Please run the above program before you sleep and see the output when you woke up in morning.. You will get your answer...

Comment: As there will be billions of iteration for loop, it will take time to run the program...